# Installtion problems in ruby

Tags: ruby

I had ruby in my Red hat linux pc. 
I manually deleted the folders of ruby in /usr/lib and /usr/bin.
Now when I try to install ruby again it says it conflicts with some files which does not exist.

rpm -i ruby-libs-1.8.6.111-1.i386.rpm

file /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/tag.rb from install of ruby-libs-1.8.6.111-1 conflicts with file from package ruby-libs-1.8.5-5.el5
and lot more files

What should I do now ?Can someone guide me.

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you really want to install that file, you can use the `--force` option:

```
rpm -i --force ruby-libs-1.8.6.111-1.i386.rpm
```

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the old installation using rpm

`rpm -qa | grep ruby`

to get see that it is installed, then

`rpm -e ruby-libs-1.8.6.111-1`

to uninstall it. Do this for other packages that are conflicting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use rvm if you want to do anything with ruby. Particularly when you're using a distro that tends to be on the conservative side.